# Step left design pattern for large number of steps on mobile

Tags: navigation, mobile-web

I'm trying to create a meal ordering process which is split across 5 steps.
I wanted to know what might be a good way to design a stepper pattern for mobile.

After researching i have narrowed down to 4 options

1) Compress the step circles and text to fit in line: readability problems, too cluttered hence going to ignore it.

2) Vertical stepper: This would be a good option but some of the steps are too "tall" for my use case and will be even "taller" on mobile hence, navigating amongst steps will not be very great as pointed out in [this answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/98389/125088) too.

3) Step X of Y pattern: This is a good alternative but a few problems here are that the user can't see all the steps and navigating directly through steps is problematic

4) Horizontal scrolling of the steppers: Apart from the scrolling i don't see any problems with this approach but i wanted to know if there is some user research on this specific topic.

So i'm unsure between approach 3 and 4 and would greatly appreciate if someone could guide me or propose an alternative that could solve the steps problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my website, I would use some of the alternatives below:

**Aletrnative 1:**

Something that works like pagnation. Basically, I will show just 2 steps at first step and last step and 3 steps for others.

See an example:

- step 1: Current Step > Next step
- step 2: First Step > Current Step > Next step > ...
- step 3: ... > Last Step > Current Step > Next Step > ...
- step 4: ... > Last Step > Current Step > Next Step > ...
- step 5: ... > Last Step > Current Step

Of course, you need to be creative working with it and you can put any text there.

**Aletrnative 2:**

[image]

**Aletrnative 3:**

[image]

**Aletrnative 4:**

[image]

**Aletrnative 5:**

I added another option where you can add some bar like this 4th example and change "< 520" for the title of the current step.

[image]

I hope that is useful and I had understood what you need.

Comment: I did try out the alternatives but 5 steps with text don't really fit without cramming it up. Other option as you suggested would be to have only the current step's text but  if i enable back navigation from the steps then there won't really be enough tap target. Also the alternative 1 is what i was wondering but with horizontal scroll. Have you ever tried a horizontal scroll step left counter? For now i have simply gone for the Step X out of Y with the current step text.

Comment: @SauravSeth Could you please insert your template here? Then I can try to help you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use as an alternative the **material Design** tabs as a reference. You can hide some unused steps but if user swipe, then he can see it.

See image example and see more in https://material.io/design/components/tabs.html#usage

[image]

**OR** like I had used on my last website. you can insert a box over the trackbar with all information.

[image]